# How much information is produced in our Society?

Tags: statistics, data, bigdata

I was reading an interesting article about the growth of data in our society:
https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2012.00584.x

[image]
Does any of you know if there exists a more recent statistic that compares the growth of data from the 70s till now?